# How to solve Local path <path> is not registered within uploads in the request in PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Professional Edition)?

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, pycharm, interpreter

I want to set up a Django project with docker-compose and PyCharm on my PC with Ubuntu 22.04 OS. Using PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Professional) I get the following error

> How to solve Local path  is not registered within uploads in the request

I added a Python interpreter from `Settings > project > Python interpreter` and then `add interpreter > on SSH` after that entered ssh credentials and on the system interpreter finally I created the Python interpreter.

I have docker-compose run on another terminal.

[image: system interpreter settings]

[image: remote interpreter settings]

After I run the `runserver` command it shows this error:

[image: chosen run configuration widget]

[image: error popup message in lower toolbar]

this is the `runserver` command configuration:

[image: run configuration]

I have recreated the interpreter, and explored the same problems on JetBrains website but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: This bug was solved in 2022.2.2, best thing you should do is update your installation! [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55396/Python-Console-fails-with-Local-path-is-not-registered-within-uploads-in-the-request-when-using-Remote-Interpreter-from-previous)

Comment: Thanks, @julienc. I downgraded the Pycharm to v2021.3 and it worked.

Comment: I posted an answer because there was [another question today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74592597) with the same bug and questions need to have an answer so they can be used as duplicate targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was reported as [PY-55396](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55396) on the JetBrains bug tracker.

The bug was solved in PyCharm 2022.2.2, the solution is to upgrade to that version or downgrade to PyCharm 2021.3.